# How to use water body data from EarthExplorer?

Tags: qgis, water, earth-explorer

I've downloaded some data from EarthExplorer that should be the water body data for the area I'm mapping. The download comes with a DBF, SHP, and SHX file. Once I load them into QGIS though, all three give me the icon for "missing CRS" so I try projecting them, but it doesn't work.

When I click Zoom to layer, they're microscopic out at 0,0. The files come with some text documents about their longitude and latitude, but I can't figure out how to line them up to the area I'm actually looking for.

Edit: Linked the [water body day](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mav6lIDvdsYjZMbbwaxrunpPsHnWwQh6/view?usp=sharing,%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZPPaV-Vmlro8AWBiunVghto0q96HW7xU/view?usp=sharing,%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c5X_1ao-J9sws8Ys6hKKdrUxhaCOj6uO/view?usp=sharing)

How can I load these in correctly?

I've attached the readme about the naming convention if that gives any hints.

[image: Pics of the files with their longitude and latitude names]

[[image: Waterbody in the middle of nowhere][2]]

Comment: 99 out of 100 times, reprojecting the data is the right call. But this is the *only* time where you want to Define the projection correctly.

Comment: Please add a link to your data.

Comment: As mentioned by Vince, define the CRS

Comment: If I want to define the projection correctly, do I need to do something besides use reproject and pick a predefined CRS?